# Why do I need so many map tiles to serve a map?

Tags: tilemill, mbtiles

It's my understanding that each map tile is a 256x256 pixel image.  So... if I'm looking at a 1400 by 1400 pixel screen... that's roughly 36 tiles to cover an entire screen (6tiles by 6tiles)... and let's say I want my map at its highest zoom level to have... 20 screens worth of area on a map... that's 700 tiles for that zoom level, and on down from there for the more zoomed-out levels.  So at most this is like 10k tiles.

I'm making a map right now of the city of Portland, Oregon... and I just exported my map tiles and converted them to pngs... and there's 1 MILLION files.  What??!?!  The highest zoom level I have is 18, and the lowest is 10.... so somehow these tiles are getting miniaturized, but I'm not sure why.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're running into is exponentiation. At each deeper zoom level, each tile is divided into 4 parts, so you have 4 times as many tiles total. And this compounds between zoom levels: so if you have 1 tile at z5, then that same *geographical area* is represented by 4*4*4*4=256 tiles at z10, or 65,536 tiles at z15.

If you're looking at a map of Portland at z10, which needs around 16 tiles to cover the screen, that area is represented by 16*4^8 tiles, which is, indeed, 1,048,576 tiles.

Comment: thanks!  It's been trouble getting 1million files onto a server.  I had to use mkfs -I 128 -i 2048  to create a file system that has unusally small block sizes.  I was running into "no space left on the disk" and eventually learned this was an Inodes problem and not a hardrive space problem.  probably tmi but to anyone else out there... good luck.

Comment: That's the reason that explains why myself and some folks at Mapbox created the MBTiles format, which TileMill and other tools use as export: SQLite is a better container for many tiny files than most filesystems, and transferring the SQLite database is much more efficient. It requires a server to extract images for requests, but it avoids lots of problems on the other hand.

Comment: yes... mbtiles files are great... but I still need to unpack them with mb-util, and then I'm faced with the same problem again - having 1million files on a server

Comment: hmmm... I didn't realize this before.  I didn't know leaflet works with mbtiles files too?  It looks like there's a plugin: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/leaflet-js/SlMWOyF4yVQ      well I'll be....  but, at this point I've gone through the trouble of just working with a directory of good old fasion pngs.  Any performance issues with serving tiles from a sqlite db instead of just a directory of images?

Comment: The Leaflet plugin kind of works technically, but not conceptually in this case - when someone visits your page, they'll download a million images. Not a desired behavior. The performance of MBTiles servers is typically incredibly fast, since pulling images from a database with good indexes is almost as fast as a disk access.

Comment: ok... so any preferred map api's if leaflet isn't going to work with mbTiles?

Comment: That's the conceptual/technical gap I was trying to make: Leaflet is not the site of the problem and switching it with a different API won't change your situation. You'll either need to use a server with MBTiles, or transfer lots and lots of tiny files - those are the two solutions.